# How to get only commits of the latest merge to a branch in git

Tags: git

So I figured out I can get the latest merge to master using `git log master --merges -1`. I would like to take this a step further and get only the latest commits from the latest merge to master. How would one do this?

For example let's say I have `master`, `staging`, `feature1` and `feature2` branches. I merge `feature1` into `staging` and then into `master`. Then I do the same with `feature2` afterwards. How do I get that happened between merging `feature2`?

Comment: You asked for "child commits" but then your example and accepted answer seem to be looking for *parent* commits, which is considerably simpler (and for which xarthnax's answer is correct). The concepts become much clearer if you draw a graph of the commits. The syntax `A..B` means "get me all commits I can find by starting at `B` and working back through its history; then, from that list, *throw away* any commit I can find by starting at `A` and and working back through its history."

Comment: @torek I believe you are right on this one, sorry for the mistake. Let me edit my question for people searching for this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `git log master --merges -1`, review the two parent commits of that merge. Then issue `git log <parent1>..<parent2> --right-only --no-merges --format=format:%H` to list the commits from the `feature2` branch.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is really simple and I think answers the question without going too heavy into command line.

Comment: `--right-only` only really makes sense for a symmetric difference, `commit1...commit2` (three dots). When using just two dots, you should get the same results with or without `--right-only`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--children` flag?

```
git log master --children --merges -1
```

or you could try

https://gist.github.com/kohsuke/7590246

Comment: I gave it a shot but that command only seems to give the latest merge from master and doesn't include any children.

Comment: You could try [kohsuke's approach git-children-of](https://gist.github.com/kohsuke/7590246). You would just need to pipe the result of your first command.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:"%H"` gives you SHA of the the last merge commit.

You can use this SHA to filter the output of `git rev-list --all --children` and limit the results to commits whose parents are the given SHA1.

```
COMMIT=`git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:"%H"`
git rev-list --all --children | grep "^${COMMIT}" | cut -f2 -d' '
```

According to [git-rev-list documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html),

> **--children**
>   Print also the children of the commit (in the form "commit child…").

So `grep "^${COMMIT}"` will ensure output will be lines that start with last merge commit.